# Is there any situation where it is impossible to use a Promise and a Deferred must be used?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, deferred

I understand on stylistic/clarity grounds that people may prefer one approach over the other but I'm trying to understand if there is any situation that you **can not** use a Promise and **must** use a Deferred.  For reference I'm using the [Q javascript library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer) but I would imagine it would be applicable to any other library and language.  I don't believe the explanation under "Deferreds are cool because..." actually describes a case where it is impossible to achieve the same thing with a simple `q.Promise()` call (and thus you have to use a `Deferred`) but I wanted to check that is correct.

Are deferreds solely about eliminating the "pyramid of doom" or is there more too them?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801283/what-are-the-differences-between-deferred-promise-and-future-in-javascript) is interesting but doesn't really tackle this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such case. It is easy to prove that you can do anything you want to do with the promise constructor and not use deferred by showing a translation between them:

```
 var deferred = {};
 var p = new Q.Promise((resolve, reject){ // always runs sync
     deferred.resolve = resolve;
     deferred.reject = reject;
 });
 deferred.promise = p;
```

The advantage of the promise constructor is the fact it's *throw safe*, that is - synchronous throws are converted to rejections which saves you from subtle bugs.

In either case, construction should be [used only rarely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Q is a pretty old library too, consider something newer and more modern.

Comment: 1. Great answer, clearly see that you can translate between the two, thanks Benjamin.  2.  Great link.  I am actually doing "You should only use deferred objects when you are converting an API to promises" because I thought the node MongoClient.connect did not pass back promises.  I see that the Typescript definition is just not up to date as it does: ["Returns: Promise if no callback passed](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect).  3. Q is old but it seems to work fine, got a recommendation of something better?  Thanks again very much :)

Comment: @AJP [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-bluebird.html)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [When would someone need to create a deferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853105/when-would-someone-need-to-create-a-deferred)