# How do I defer an ES6 promise like jquery Deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, deferred, es6-promise

#### 1. Using es6 promise, but the syntax is incorrect.

I'm using es6, and want to make a deferred confirm dialog:

```
// First, create an empty promise:
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})

// Then, show the dialog:
let $dialog = $('#dialog-confirm').show();

// FAIL: I want to trigger the promise resolver, but failed.
$dialog.find('.btn-yes').click(() => { promise.resolve(); })
$dialog.find('.btn-no').click(() => { promise.reject(); })
```

When I clicked the button, it failed, because the promise does not have the `reject` and `resolve` method.

> Uncaught TypeError: promise.resolve is not a function(…)

#### 2. jQuery working code:

If using jQuery, we can do the below:

```
// First, create an empty promise:
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var promise = dfd.promise();

// Then, show the dialog:
var $dialog = $('#dialog-confirm').show();

// SUCCESS: jQuery deferred works
$dialog.find('.btn-yes').click(() => { dfd.resolve(); })
$dialog.find('.btn-no').click(() => { dfd.reject(); })
```

#### 3. Try to find a deferred interface for es6.

So I searched for an **ES6 EDITION** of deferred:

https://github.com/seangenabe/es6-deferred

But still I got an error:

> undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {}

In fact, the code is just keep the inner `resolve` and `reject` function to outside using closure:

https://github.com/seangenabe/es6-deferred/blob/master/deferred.js

The same strategy if I do:

```
let dfd = {};

let $dialog = $('#dialog-confirm').show();

let promise = (function() {
    return dfd.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        dfd.resolve = resolve;
        dfd.reject = reject;
    });
})();

// FAIL: still not working.
$dialog.find('.btn-yes').click(() => { dfd.resolve(); })
$dialog.find('.btn-no').click(() => { dfd.reject(); })
```

So, how can I pull out the `resolve` and `reject` action out of my promise creation call?

Comment: What is purpose of using `Promise`? `.then()` does not appear at Question?

Comment: This question has been asked many times.  A deferred object was not built into ES6 promises because it simply isn't needed as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853105/when-would-someone-need-to-create-a-deferred/32857145#32857145).  And, if you want to manufacture one, it takes only a few lines of ES6 code to do so.

Comment: In fact, I'm using vuex, I create the promise to pop out the dialog in the vuex actions, but I need to resolve or reject the promise in the component.

Comment: `Promise` is resolved or rejected at `javascript` at Question, though no value or reason passed as parameter?

Comment: @guest271314 `promise.then(function() { $dialog.hide(); })`

Comment: @fish_ball At `click` which element?

Comment: @guest271314 the dialog has two buttons: `.btn-yes` and `.btn-no`

Comment: No value is passed to `resolve` or  `reject` ?

Comment: How to create a deferred in a few lines of ES6 promise code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534 (though you should NEVER need to do so).

Comment: What is purpose of using `.click()` where `Promise` would be resolved or rejected once? You could utilize `$.fn.one()` to achieve same result? Not certain why you cannot use `jQuery.Deferred()` if you are using other jQuery functions? Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate issue?

Comment: Why are you using a Promise to control the visibility of a dialog anyway? What's wrong with using regular event handlers?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For those of you getting here from Google its worth mentioning that ES6 promises are good and I use them a lot. However, there are use cases where the deferred pattern results in significantly less code. In most cases you should likely just use the ES6 promises but in those special cases where the deferred pattern makes sense then its easy enough to wrap an ES6 promise. Including a node module seems like over kill in my mind.

```
function generateDeferredPromise() {
  let resolve, reject;
  const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    [resolve, reject] = [res, rej];
  });
  return {promise, reject, resolve};
}
```

Comment: Why does it need an IIFE?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa Seemed not required.

Comment: I was trying to create exactly this but couldn't figure out how to map my `resolve` and `reject` to the ones inside the scope of the Promise. This is great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move jquery statements inside the promise

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 let $dialog = $('#dialog-confirm').show();
$dialog.find('.btn-yes').click(() => { resolve(); })
$dialog.find('.btn-no').click(() => { reject(); })

})
```

Comment: I use vue framework so the triggering point is separated into different code files.

Comment: I return the dfd or promise object outside, and trigger the resolve action in other script file.

Comment: you can pass the entire  function to the promise from the another file
let promise = new Promise(yourfunction_imported)

Comment: That breaks my design. So I asked for a solution.

Comment: @fish_ball Why is the code where you attach the dialog's events in a different file from where you are creating the promise? Please explain that clearly in your question (preferably using code examples). So far you have only asked us how to make a specific implementation when you should be asking how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Deferred = require('es6-deferred');
var d = new Deferred(
     (resolve, reject) => {
         // Process your Async or sync process here and
         // call resolve() and pass your data as argument when
         // it is successful
         // same for error case, just call reject() instead.
     }
);

d.then(
    (res) => {
    // res is your data passed into the resolve method the deferred promise
    // Handle your click here
    }, (err) => {
    // err is your data or error passed into the reject method
    // Handle your click here
  }
);
```

Comment: Using a node module for 10 lines of code? Reminds me to this: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/ (whoever used this module deserved the broke of their projects, it is a very easily implementable utility function, like this).

Comment: @Disfigure - I think the point is that creating a deferred from an ES6 promise is only 8 lines of code as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534

Comment: My example does not use that module - it was originally written code.  It is similar code because that's just how you do it.

Comment: Does not answer the question as it is not a native es6 promise solution.