# Can I resolve a promise when a variable change without using deferr?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise, q

I am converting some Q-promise based typescript code to ES6-promises.

At a certain point, I used Q.defer and in my migration I just rewritten defer as an ES6 promise like explained in this comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825137/13116953

I was trying to get rid of this defer approach, if possible, and was looking for alternative solutions.

Reasons of my question are:

1. Deferred promises are considered an anti-pattern, in general
2. Want to know if this scenario is one of the few where deferred are really the only way

Here's my scenario:

```
// app start, this is my low level API
init() {
    commService.subscribe("myRecordId", {
        onRecordAdd: this.onAdd
    });
}

...

private _myRecord: MyRecordObj | null = null;
private _recordReceivedDef = newDeferred(); // was Q.defer()

// callback will be called when record is received
private readonly onAdd = (recordObj: MyRecordObj) => {
    this._myRecord = recordObj;
    this._recordReceivedDef.resolve(recordObj);
}

...

// here's my async code that requires the deferred
public readonly doStuff = async () => {
    // ...
    const myRec = await this._recordReceivedDef.promise;
    // use myRef
}
```

My question is: **is there a way I can get rid of this defer?**
I was thinking of something that resolves when `_myRecord` changes, but have no idea how to do it.

Side note:
I use MobX in other parts of our app, thus having

```
await when(() => this._myRecord); // of course _myRecord must be @observable
```

would be handy, but unfortunately I cannot use MobX in this particular piece of code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `init` is called before `doStuff`, the proper way would be

```
init() {
    this._myRecordPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commService.subscribe("myRecordId", {
            onRecordAdd: (recordObj: MyRecordObj) => {
                // callback will be called when record is received
                resolve(this._myRecord = recordObj);
            }
        });
    });
}

…

private _myRecord: MyRecordObj | null = null;
private _myRecordPromise: Promise<MyRecordObj>;

…

public readonly doStuff = async () => {
    …
    const myRec = await this._myRecordPromise;
    // use myRef
}
```

You might even drop the `_myRecord` completely and keep only the `_myRecordPromise`.

However, you might want to consider not constructing your instance at all before the record is received, see [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).

If `init` is called at some arbitrary time, you will need some kind of defer pattern, but you don't need `newDeferred()` for that. Just write

```
init() {
    commService.subscribe("myRecordId", {
        onRecordAdd: this.onAdd
    });
}

…

private _myRecordPromise: Promise<MyRecordObj> = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.onAdd = resolve;
});
private readonly onAdd: (recordObj: MyRecordObj) => void;
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to see Promises from the right perspective

Answer (score 0):

For people who might be interested, there is also another solution that uses an event emitter approach.
Suppose you have a class EventEmitter that implements the following interface:

```js
// pseudo code
type UnsubscribeFn = () => void;
interface IEventEmitter<T> {
    /** Fires an event */
    emit(args: T): void;
    /** Subscribes to emissions of this event and provides an unsubscribe function */
    subscribe((args: T) => void): UnsubscribeFn;
}
```

you can provide your clients with a `whenAdded` function like below

```js
// pseudo code
class Subscriber {
    readonly onAddEmitter = new EventEmitter<MyRecordObj>();

    // app start
    init() {
        commService.subscribe("myRecordId", {
            onRecordAdd: this.onAdd
        });
    }
    
    onAdd = (rec: MyRecordObj) => {
           // do some stuff
           onAddEmitter.emit(rec);
    }
    
    whenAdded(): Promise<MyRecordObj> {
        return new Promise((res) => {
            const unsub = onAddEmitter.subscribe((record: MyRecordObj) => {
                unsub();
               res(record); 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The goals achieved are:

- Get rid of Q promises in favour of ES6 ones
- Adapt the `commService` event API to a promise-based one