# Pure JavaScript $.Deferred

Tags: javascript, promise

How would I write the following without jQuery?

```js
var dfd = $.Deferred()
dfd.done(done)
dfd.resolve()

function done() {
   console.log('done')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can't you use ES6 promises directly? Plus, your deferred (aka promise) is resolved directly without any async job, but I guess your reallife usecase is different?

Comment: Yes, I can. Yes, my real life use case needs to wait until something else happens.

Comment: Deferreds are pretty much considered an anti-pattern now and there is a reason they are not directly supported in ES6.  What problem are you really trying to solve?  Any basic tutorial on ES6-standard promises will show you how a standard promise can be created and resolved using the Promise executor.  Are you specifically asking how you make a deferred object (something that is now frowned upon) in ES6?  Or what is the real problem to solve here?  With as much rep as you have, you should be able to write a more complete and meaningful question.

Comment: For a discussion of deferreds (instead of promises) being an anti-pattern, see here: [When would someone need to create a deferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853105/when-would-someone-need-to-create-a-deferred/32857145#32857145).

Comment: And, for an example of creating a deferred using standard promises, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
    function Deferred (){
      let res,rej,p = new Promise((a,b)=>(res = a, rej = b));
      p.resolve = res;
      p.reject = rej;
      return p;
    }
```

You just need to expose resolve and reject to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Use native *promises*:

```
Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(done);

function done() {
   console.log('done')
}
```

**Update**

Without the chain:

```
let op = Promise.resolve();
op.then(done);

function done() {
   console.log('done')
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to break this into 2 lines of code instead of a chain?

Comment: Is there a way to break `let op = Promise.resolve();` into 2 lines?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why you need this, but maybe this: `let promise = Promise; op = promise.resolve()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using native promises is that the resolve and reject handler is provided in the callback, so if you try and call them before they are actually assigned.

In my opinion it's more robust to just implement a deferred yourself for example:

```js
function deferred() {
  let thens = []
  let catches = []

  let status
  let resolvedValue
  let rejectedError

  return {
    resolve: value => {
      status = 'resolved'
      resolvedValue = value
      thens.forEach(t => t(value))
      thens = [] // Avoid memleaks.
    },
    reject: error => {
      status = 'rejected'
      rejectedError = error
      catches.forEach(c => c(error))
      catches = [] // Avoid memleaks.
    },
    then: cb => {
      if (status === 'resolved') {
        cb(resolvedValue)
      } else {
        thens.unshift(cb)
      }
    },
    catch: cb => {
      if (status === 'rejected') {
        cb(rejectedError)
      } else {
        catches.unshift(cb)
      }
    },
  }
}

const d = deferred()

setTimeout(() => {
  d.resolve('good')
}, 1000)

// Will be called after 1s
d.then(value => console.log('#1 resolved!', value))

setTimeout(() => {
  // Will be called after 3s and executed right away as it's already resolved
  d.then(value => console.log('#2 resolved!', value))
}, 3000)
```