# Is there any downside to exposing resolve() and reject() outside of the Promise constructor?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I created this little helper to expose `resolve` and `reject` outside of the Promise's constructor

```
export function createPromise() {
    let resolve,reject;
    let promise = new Promise((r,j) => {
        resolve = r;
        reject = j;
    });
    Object.assign(promise,{resolve,reject});
    return promise;
}
```

Because sometimes it's just really awkward to wrap your entire script in

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
   // hundreds of lines of code, most which have nothing 
   // to do with this Promise but I need the Promise object 
   // at the top level somewhere so that I can expose it, 
   // but it won't be resolved until some deeply nested construct is hit  
})
```

Or to give a more concrete example:

```
let p1 = kb.createPromise();
let p2 = kb.createPromise();

Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(() => {
    $('#calendar-bookings').scrollIntoView({
        duration: 200,
        direction: 'y'
    });
});

$('#bookings-table')
    .dataTable(getOptions(dtSourceUrl, {date, driverOptions}))
    .one('draw.dt', () => p1.resolve());

ReactDOM.render(<VehicleTimeline start={dateMom.toDate()} onLoad={() => p2.resolve()}/>, document.getElementById('vehicle-timeline'));
```

<del>This way I also don't have to worry about whether `resolve()` is called synchronously before I even get a chance to bind my `.then`.</del> [I stand corrected, the `.then` will fire immediately] I think this is pretty clear: create two promises, bind the `.then`, and *only after* is it even conceivable that they're resolved.

Sure, this would allow anyone who you've passed your Promise off to to resolve it (i.e. giving control away from the Promise creator and to the consumer) but if the consumer fires it early, that's their loss because presumably they're the ones interested in the event, no?

Also, this would give the consumer the ability to reject() the Promise which they could abuse as a sort of Promise cancellation. I'm not saying that's a good idea, but I don't think the extra freedom is necessarily bad either.

Is there anything else I'm missing? Any problems with my `createPromise` method?

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) (and reject)? That way you can bypass the whole issue without this awkward construct.

Comment: @Nit That creates a new Promise that's already resolved. I'm not sure how that helps?

Comment: This seems to be pretty close to top "related" question, [Resolve Javascript Promise outside function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26150232/1426891), which argues that your type of function is rarely-needed but effective. Yours is much more elegant, though! Marking as dupe, but feel free to ignore/edit if yours has different constraints/concerns.

Comment: You can do it, but it makes flow less obvious and can be pretty confusing. Plus with decoupling resolve/reject functions from corresponding promise you need to handle exceptions separately twice.

Comment: Why do you " worry about whether resolve() is called synchronously before I even get a chance to bind my .then"? The `then` method can be called before or after a promise becomes settled without changing the effect...

Comment: This is discussed here: [When would someone need to create a deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853105/when-would-someone-need-to-create-a-deferred/32857145#32857145).

Comment: "*hundreds of lines of code, most which have nothing to do with this Promise*" - there's your actual problem. Just don't put those inside the promise constructor. Construct the promise only in the one place where you actually are going to resolve it (in your example, around the `.one` and `.render` calls), and if you really have "*some deeply nested construct*" then use functions that *`return`* the promise they constructed deep in their bowels.

Comment: The downside is maintainability. Formulated pointedly, you have a messy spaghetti code structure and you need to affect a promise that is 200 lines away. Your question "What's wrong with exposing the resolver functions?" is essentially the same as "What's wrong with just introducing a global variable for a callback that I can invoke from anywhere?". Yes, this will work, and not much work to implement, but the proper solution is obviously to fix the architecture.

Comment: @Traktor53 Oops... you're quite right. The `.then` will just fire immediately. I thought I'd have "missed" the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the `deferred` pattern except that you return the promise object with the resolve/reject functions in the promise object. The original `deferred` pattern created an object with the promise and the resolve/reject functions separately. So you can pass out the promise without exposing the controls.

To be honest, there are very little places where actually breaking out of the constructor scope is needed. In my opinion it's a little bit easier to make a mistake with this pattern and end up with unresolved promises than with the constructor pattern. As far as I can tell really, the only benefit from the constructor pattern over the deferred pattern that you get is that you can throw and reject the promise immediately (through a sync mistake).